# SwiftUI is it ok to use hashValue in Identifiable

Tags: ios, swiftui

For structs, Swift auto synthesizes the hashValue for us. So I am tempting to just use it to conform to the identifiable.

I understand that hashValue is many to one, but ID must be one to one. However, hash collision is very rare and I have faith in the math that it's most likely never going to happen to my app before I die.

I am wondering is there any other problems besides collision?

This is my code:

```
public protocol HashIdentifiable: Hashable & Identifiable {}

public extension HashIdentifiable {
  var id: Int {
    return hashValue
  }
}
```

Comment: You are forgetting a major problem in your reasoning. The same value. Tow different objects with the same value will have the same hash value, even though they are different objects. Humans categorize and equate things. It is MUCH more likely that the values are the same than the hash values of different values are the same. This is why we have a UUID.

Comment: @Yrb Is what you have described common for a SwiftUI List Row?

Comment: @John Absolutely. There is nothing surprising about a List with two equal values in it. Even if done by accident (for example, someone adding the same todo item twice), you would want to display both rather than silently (and in a buggy way) merging them.

Answer (score 6):

using `hashValue` for `id` is a bad idea !

for example you have 2 structs

```
struct HashID: HashIdentifiable {
    var number: Int
}

struct NormalID: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var number: Int
}
```

when `number` is changed:

- `HashID`'s `id` will be changed as well makes `SwiftUI` thinks that this is completely new item and old one is gone
- `NormalID`'s `id` stays the same, so `SwiftUI` knows that item only modified its property

It's very important to let `SwiftUI` knows what's going on, because it will affect animations, performance, ... That's why using `hashValue` for `id` makes your code looks bad and you should stay away from it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering is there any other problems besides collision?

Yes, many.

E.g., with this…

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var toggleData = (1...5).map(ToggleDatum.init)

  var body: some View {
    List($toggleData) { $datum in
      Toggle(datum.display, isOn: $datum.value)
    }
  }
}
```

1. Collisions cause complete visual chaos.

```swift
struct ToggleDatum: Identifiable & Hashable {
  var value: Bool = false
  var id: Int { hashValue }
  var display: String { "\(id)" }

  init(id: Int) {
    // Disregard for now.
  }
}
```

2. No collisions, with unstable identifiers, breaks your contract of "[identity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable)" and kills animation. Performance will suffer too, but nobody will care about that when it's so ugly even before they notice any slowness or battery drain.

```swift
struct ToggleDatum: Identifiable & Hashable {
  var value: Bool = false
  var id: Int { hashValue }
  let display: String

  init(id: Int) {
    self.display = "\(id)"
  }
}
```

---

However, while it is not acceptable to use the hash value as an identifier, it is fine to do the **opposite**: use the identifier for hashing, as long as you know the IDs to be unique for the usage set.

```swift
/// An `Identifiable` instance that uses its `id` for hashability.
public protocol HashableViaID: Hashable, Identifiable { }

// MARK: - Hashable
public extension HashableViaID {
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
  }
}
```

```swift
struct ToggleDatum: HashableViaID {
  var value: Bool = false
  let id: Int
  var display: String { "\(id)" }

  init(id: Int) {
    self.id = id
  }
}
```

This protocol works perfectly for `Equatable` classes, as classes [already have a default ID](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Identifiable.swift) ready for use.

```swift
extension Identifiable where Self: AnyObject {
  public var id: ObjectIdentifier {
    return ObjectIdentifier(self)
  }
}
```

Not that I at all recommend using a reference type for this example, but it would look like this:

```swift
public extension Equatable where Self: AnyObject {
  static func == (class0: Self, class1: Self) -> Bool {
    class0 === class1
  }
}

class ToggleDatum: HashableViaID {
```